# Synchronize columns of two matrices

Tags: awk, perl

Please guide on how to solve this problem. I have pairs of files which I need to modify so that they have the same common columns  in the same sequence.

If my files are File1 and File2 as follows

```
  R1 C1 C2 C3 C4
  R2 1 2 3 4 
  R3 5 6 7 8


  R6 C4 C3 C6 C7
  R7 9 10 11 12
  R8 13 14 15 16
```

I am looking for mod_File1 and mod_File2

```
  R1 C3 C4
  R2 3 4 
  R3 7 8

  R6 C3 C4
  R7 10 9
  R8 14 13
```

Here is what I tried

```
awk '
  FNR==1        {F++}
  F==1          {
        if (NR==1) 
        for (i=2;i<NF;i++) 
        {
        col1[$i];
        }
        next
        }
  F==2          {
        if (NR==1) 
        for (i=2;i<NF;i++) 
        {
        col2[$i];
        }
        next
        }
  F=3           {   NR==1 { 
            for (i=2;i<NF;i++)
                         if ($i in cols2)
                         c1[i];
                          }
                    NR>1 { for (j in c1)
                        print $j >> mod_file1
                 }
  F=4           {   NR==1 { 
            for (i=2;i<NF;i++)
                             if ($i in cols1)
                             c1[i];
                           }
                     NR>1 { for (j in c1)
                        print $j >> mod_file2
                 }
     ' file1 file1 file2 file2
```

Comment: When you're doing something this complicated, it might be time to leave the realm of shell scripting and switch to a proper programming language, like for example Python, especially given that the task does not involve the shell at all.

Comment: I`m not familiar with python at all, so I wouldn't know how to get started. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: _"I need to modify so that they have the same common columns in the same sequence."_  Your modified files differ in column 1.  Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, the first column is row names, sorry I should have mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit more complicated than it seems - there's probably a library that would do this better (there's a lot of maths libraries in perl).

But this should do approximately what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


#read file 1
open( my $file1, "<", "data1.txt" ) or die $!;

my $header_line = <$file1>;
chomp($header_line);
my ( $column1, @headers1 ) = split( ' ', $header_line );

my %results;
my %headers_in_file1 = map { $_ => 1 } @headers1;

for (<$file1>) {
    my ( $column, @values ) = split;
    my %these_results;
    @these_results{@headers1} = @values;
    $results{$column}         = \%these_results;
}
close ( $file1);


#read file 2
open( my $file2, "<", "data2.txt" ) or die $!;
$header_line = <$file2>;
chomp($header_line);
my ( $column2, @headers2 ) = split( ' ', $header_line );

my %results2;
my %headers_in_file2 = map { $_ => 1 } @headers2;

for (<$file2>) {
    my ( $column, @values ) = split;
    my %these_results;
    @these_results{@headers2} = @values;
    $results2{$column}        = \%these_results;
}
close ( $file2 );

#figure out the columns in both
my %in_both;
foreach my $header ( @headers1, @headers2 ) {
    if (    $headers_in_file1{$header}
        and $headers_in_file2{$header} )
    {
        $in_both{$header}++;
    }
}

#sort out headers for output. 
my @output_headers = sort keys %in_both;

print join( " ", $column1, @output_headers ), "\n";
foreach my $row ( sort keys %results ) {
    print $row, " ";
    for my $header (@output_headers) {
        print $results{$row}{$header}, " ";
    }
    print "\n";
}

print "Second\n";
print join( " ", $column2, @output_headers ), "\n";
foreach my $row ( sort keys %results2 ) {
    print $row, " ";
    for my $header (@output_headers) {
        print $results2{$row}{$header}, " ";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: works wonderfully. thanks a ton, I will get back to you if this fails with my gigantic datasets.